# Remote SSH copy files with filenames that contain certain strings

Tags: linux, scp, remote, file-copy, sftp

I have two remote servers. One that I am currently connected to and one that I am trying to copy a lot of files to (`10.10.0.13`)

I have a series of files I need to copy within various directories of the format:

```
/opt/DR/output/1/a/csva1file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/a/csva2file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb1file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb2file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb3file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/b/csvb4file.csv
/opt/DR/output/1/c/csvc1file.csv
...
/opt/DR/output/30/a/csva1file.csv
```

And this continues for `output/1` to `output/40` folders. All the folders inside are identical and all the filenames inside will all contain similar strings, just with slight differences depending on the folder they are in.

I want to copy all the files that contain `a1` from any directory to a folder in a remote server:

```
root@10.10.0.13:/data/landing/a/a1/
```

Similarly, I want to do this for all `b1`, `c1`, `c2` etc. files and copy them to their respective places on the remote server.

I cannot seem to find a way to do this that doesn't involve writing multiple lines of code.

I have tried

```
cd /opt/DR/output/1/a/
scp -r -v *a1* root@10.10.0.13:/data/landing/a/a1/
```

which works but I want to copy all the `*a1*` csv files rather than having to do them one by one.

I have looked into globbing but don't think it can be used for my case. I have also looked at using `paramiko/glob` for python but I couldn't get that to work either. Ideally, I would like to do this with a bash shell script, but a python script would also work.

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can copy via `SFTP` or `SCP`.

Comment: Do you have any list of those `b1`, `c1`, `c2`, etc?

Comment: "_for all b1, c1, c2 etc. files_" I don't see the pattern. Is it that directory `/1/a/` contains `*a1*` files, and `/99/z/` would hypothetically contain `*z99*` files? If not, please clarify how we know what your "_etc._" is to represent.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple bash script for your task. Just replace BASE string on your directory in local machine, and replace SSH_BASE string on your remote machine.
I hope this helps. *nesting is 2*

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

BASE="/opt/DR/output"
SSH_BASE="/data/landing"
for i in `ls ${BASE}`
do
    if [ -d ${BASE}/${i} ]; then
        for j in `ls ${BASE}/${i}`
        do
            if [ -d ${BASE}/${i}/${j} ]; then 
             ssh root@10.10.0.13 "mkdir -p ${SSH_BASE}/${i}/${j}"
             scp ${BASE}/${i}/${j}/*.* root@10.10.0.13:${SSH_BASE}/${i}/${j}/
            fi      
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Please do not parse `ls`. Use at least `ls -1` for more robustness. Better: `for i in "$BASE"/*; do` if the contents is not too much, otherwise `while IFS= read -r i; do ...;  done < <(ls -1 "$BASE")`.

Comment: When you'll run ssh command inside WHILE IFS, your script may stops. Not good idea. MB this: for I in "$BASE"/*, really better than my code, but no sure

Comment: For the ssh command to work in a while-loop, stdin must be redirected from `/dev/null`. This could be achieved by explicilty redirecting with `< /dev/null`, or using the parameter `-n` to the `ssh` command, which does the same.